# CTRL+F not working on android studio logcat

Tags: android-studio

Unable to search using the CTRL+F search functionality inside the android studio logcat. Is there way to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify keyboard setting.
This function shortcut is in Mainmenu/Edit/Find/Find
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Slark, It solved my problem after three years.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need "Find" func in logcat. Use upper pannel which doing this function

[image]

Comment: The upper panel is less effective in a few cases. For e.g: When there is a huge API response and we need to find a specific key (which is repeated multiple times) and its value, the upper panel will be of less help.